# How can I pass value from a Activity of one app to Application of another app

Tags: android-activity, android

We pass values across activities using Intent's extra DS. If I need to pass value from a `Activity` to `Application` , what is the best way to do it?

I used `SharedPreferences`, however I am unable to see the values being set.

I used

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString(CURRENT_AIRLINE_IATA_CODE, AIRLINE_CODE);`

To read it, I used

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(CURRENT_AIRLINE_IATA_CODE, null);`

Android documentation states SharedPreferences cannot be used to pass information across different processes `Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later.` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Did you commit the changes to the editor? Like PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString(CURRENT_AIRLINE_IATA_CODE, AIRLINE_CODE).commit();

Comment: No, I did not commit.

Comment: You mean you want to pass a value from one of your activity to the class which extends Application?

Comment: If you do not commit, your changes don't get saved. That's why you can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

set like this

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("send","hello");
```

get like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                "newshare",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         prefs.getString("send","not found");
```

Comment: `SharedPreferences` wont work on multiple process. I want to send data from one app to another app.Android documentation tells `Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later.`

Answer (score 0):

You can just store values in the Application if you make it something like this.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication singleton;
    private Object value;

    // Returns the application instance 
    public static TVGidsApplication getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    public final void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate() 
        singleton = this;
    }  

    public Object getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

then from any `Activity` (or even any other class) you can pass values to the application by calling `MyApplication.getInstance().setValue(value)`
and get it from any `Activity` by calling `MyApplication.getInstance().getValue()`.
`value` can of course also be any other type than `Object`

Comment: How will this work for an activity of one app to communicate with application of another app?

Comment: That will not work this way. I thought you needed to access the Application class with Activities of the same app. I don't know how you can do it across apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void record(String key,Context context,String value)
{

    SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences .Editor editor=pref.edit();

    editor.putString(key,value );
    editor.commit();


}



public static String getRecord(String key,Context context)
{
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(key,PREF_DEFAULT_VALUE);

}
```

you can store and get preferences by using these methods...hope it will help.